How to decode account data using Rust?
I'm trying to get the account data using Rust and the solana_sdk.
I have the following code where account.data is a Vec.
    let pubkey = Pubkey::from_str("4qRdUCHMGAfBEE3MNTiZZXpx3DawAWpGwDpqE2EV2QQ2").unwrap();

    let account = client.get_account(&pubkey).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", account.data);


When trying to decode the byte array:
    let data = String::from_utf8(account.data).unwrap();

I get an error:
error: Utf8Error { valid_up_to: 1, error_len: Some(1) } }

How can I decode account data using Rust?

The cookbook doc does not help here? https://solanacookbook.com/guides/get-program-accounts.html#facts

Not that I can find? Please be more specific if you have any pointers.
In this specific case I'm trying to decode/deserialize a metadata account, but whatever what I try I'm not able to decode the "data" property.

Can you please elaborate a bit on what you mean? If you talk about Solana account metadata then it's just the predefined set of things (lamports, executable, pubkey) https://solana.com/docs/core/accounts that brings data which is a set of bytes where every program on Solana decides on its own what how to encode/decode. What is the Metadata account more specifically? Do you have your code somewhere?

@chalda I updated the code now with a pubkey of a metadata account.
But the problem is just in general for all metadata accounts. How can I read/decode the "data" property? account.data to be specific.

Ok. The data of the account is just a buffer of bytes. There is no meaning in them. The schema is defined by a program that loads them on-chain. Every program works with a different schema and you need to know what program you want to work with (see https://github.com/Unboxed-Software/solana-course/blob/main/content/deserialize-custom-data.md#deserializing-program-data). There are standards to define schema (the mostly used Anchor IDL) that maps the order and size of bytes slices in the buffer to "a meaning". Search for deserialised solana (Anchor) data here in other topics.

Thank you. You pointed me in the right direction.
mpl_token_metadata::accounts::Metadata has a from_bytes function which serializes the data into a Metadata struct (the schema you're referring to).
Added an answer based on this.

mpl_token_metadata::accounts::Metadata has a function from_bytes which serializes the bytes into a Metadata struct:
let meta: Metadata = Metadata::from_bytes(&account.data).unwrap();

